# How to get month name and am/pm in lowercase

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatting

How to get month name and am/pm in lowercase

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM h:m tt");
```

this giving me capital letters, but I want small letters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to use ToLower method

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM h:m tt").ToLower();
```

Answer (score 5):

Given that everything else will be numeric, I think it's going to be easiest just to call `ToLower` on the result. I don't think there's anything you can do in the format string to force it to lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateFormat Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and this static method will convert it to lower am pm

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   String inFormat = "d MMM yyyy,h:mm aa";
   String dateString = DateFormat.format(inFormat, calendar).toString();
```

By converting the string into lowercase (which you are doing) your month will also be get converted into lower case suppose your the month is **July** then it will be converted to **july**. SO i think u can use the above method to convert specifically only am_pm into lower case